# Converting docx to pdf in java

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, converters

I am using below code-

[image: codeImage]

The external dependency used are -

[image: externalDependency]
I am getting the error below as -

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-11",
    "message": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle.getDefault()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/STOnOff$Enum;",
    "details": "uri=/pdf"
}
```

Comment: The fact you have three different versions of xdocreport dependencies looks suspicious to me. I suspect you need to use the same version (2.0.3) for all three of those dependencies. Similarly, the fact you have two Apache POI dependency versions is very suspicious (5.2.2 and 4.1.2). Please make sure your dependencies are consistent and compatible, as that is likely the cause of the NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Also, for future reference, please do not post images of code, post them as code-formatted text.

Comment: After using same versions , i am getting "message": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory",

Comment: That suggests you still have some incompatible combination of libraries. Check the documentation of all those libraries to see which dependency versions they require.

Comment: For future questions, please observe: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Rather consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].